# Convert Json property based on property value

Tags: c#, json

I would like to deserialize a json to object. The json is like below. But one property value maybe string or array, does anyone know how to handle this?

```
{
  "name": "123", //Name
  "properties": [
    {
      "propertyId": "Subject", // property id
      "value": [
        {
          "entityId": "math", //entity id
          "entityTypeId": "MATH" //entity type id 
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "propertyId": "Description",
      "value": "Hello World."
    }
  ]
}
```

The class is like below.

```
//The object
public class Content
{
public Content()
{
//Properties is List.
Properties = new List<Property>();
}

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
public string Name { get; set; }

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "properties")]
public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class Property
{
public Property()
{
Value = new List<Value>();
}

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "propertyId")]
public string PropertyDefId { get; set; }

//Actually this property value can also be string, that's the problem.
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
public List<Value> Value { get; set; }
}

//Value object
public class Value
{
//Have to write comments.
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "entityId")]
public string EntityId { get; set; }

//Have to write comments.
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "entityTypeId")]
public string EntityTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What about just declaring `Value` as `object`?

Comment: Don't have time to check right now, but probably you can use type: `JObject`

Comment: @Lloyd It works, but I'd like to convert it as a specific type here (Value). So the goal is, if value in Json is "123" then convert it as string, if value is an array in Json then convert it as Value type.

Comment: Yeh that won't work, you need to use some kind of generic type or dynamic, the lowest common denominator.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in Java with Gson liblary and it was like

```
JsonObject field = parser.parse(json).getElementAsJSONObject();
if (field.isPrimitive()) {
  String text = field.asString();
} else if (field.isArray()) {
  JSONArray array = field.asArray();
}
```

I wrote this code from my memory so not 100% reliable. I don't know any solution for C# though.

Answer (score -1):

$.parseJSON will convert your string to the correct object even if the property type is different for two different properties.

http://jsfiddle.net/mdanielc/e0acsyp1/2/

```
var jsonString = '{"name": "123","properties": [{"propertyId": "Subject","value": [{"entityId":"math","entityTypeId": "MATH" }]},{"propertyId": "Description","value": "Hello World."}]}';
var jsonobj = $.parseJSON(jsonString);

alert(jsonobj.properties[0].value[0].entityId);
alert(jsonobj.properties[1].value);
```

});